# Anaconda installer exits after unpacking payload and does not install anything

Tags: macos, installation, anaconda, macos-catalina, anaconda3

As everyone, after the upgrade I couldn't use anaconda. At the end I erased everything and downloaded it again to install it from scratch.
I am using Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7
During installation it says 'unpacking payload' and it extracts some files. After that, nothing happens, no error message, nothing.

[image]

If I go to /Users/Nebula/anaconda3/ there are only a few files. There is no bin folder.

[image]

Basically it is not installed at all. The same happens if I do it with the graphical installer.

___update:
I tried with bash and zsh, both the same.
Then I tried with brew install anaconda and I get this error.

[image]

it doesn't install it either.

____update2:
I have been trying with several versions and I manage to install a version from 2018. However when I run conda it shows: An unexpected error has occurred.

____update3:
I have run it with bash -x Here is the output. At the end it seems it is trying to run conda.exe which is weird being a mac. It asks for y/N and it exits whether I answer yes or no.

```
Nebula@Infinitys-MacBook-Pro ~ % bash -x Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
+ unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
+ echo Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
+ grep '\.sh$'
+ '[' -n /bin/zsh ']'
+ RUNNING_SHELL=/bin/zsh
+ '[' -z /bin/zsh ']'
+ '[' '!' -f /bin/zsh ']'
+ '[' -z /bin/zsh ']'
+ '[' '!' -f /bin/zsh ']'
+++ dirname Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
++ DIRNAME=Downloads
++ cd Downloads
++ pwd
+ THIS_DIR=/Users/Nebula/Downloads
++ basename Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
+ THIS_FILE=Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
+ THIS_PATH=/Users/Nebula/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
+ PREFIX=/Users/Nebula/anaconda3
+ BATCH=0
+ FORCE=0
+ SKIP_SCRIPTS=0
+ TEST=0
+ REINSTALL=0
+ USAGE='
usage: Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh [options]

Installs Anaconda3 2020.11

-b           run install in batch mode (without manual intervention),
             it is expected the license terms are agreed upon
-f           no error if install prefix already exists
-h           print this help message and exit
-p PREFIX    install prefix, defaults to /Users/Nebula/anaconda3, must not contain spaces.
-s           skip running pre/post-link/install scripts
-u           update an existing installation
-t           run package tests after installation (may install conda-build)
'
+ which getopt
++ getopt bfhp:sut ''
+ OPTS=' -- '
+ '[' '!' 0 ']'
+ eval set -- ' -- '
++ set -- --
+ true
+ case "$1" in
+ shift
+ break
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
++ uname -m
+ '[' x86_64 '!=' x86_64 ']'
++ uname
+ '[' Darwin '!=' Darwin ']'
+ printf '\n'

+ printf 'Welcome to Anaconda3 2020.11\n'
Welcome to Anaconda3 2020.11
+ printf '\n'

+ printf 'In order to continue the installation process, please review the license\n'
In order to continue the installation process, please review the license
+ printf 'agreement.\n'
agreement.
+ printf 'Please, press ENTER to continue\n'
Please, press ENTER to continue
+ printf '>>> '
>>> + read -r dummy
Do you accept the license terms? [yes|no]
+ printf '[no] >>> '
[no] >>> + read -r ans
yes
+ '[' yes '!=' yes ']'
+ '[' yes '!=' yes ']'
+ printf '\n'

+ printf 'Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:\n'
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
+ printf '%s\n' /Users/Nebula/anaconda3
/Users/Nebula/anaconda3
+ printf '\n'

+ printf '  - Press ENTER to confirm the location\n'
 - Press ENTER to confirm the location
+ printf '  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation\n'
 - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
+ printf '  - Or specify a different location below\n'
 - Or specify a different location below
+ printf '\n'

+ printf '[%s] >>> ' /Users/Nebula/anaconda3
[/Users/Nebula/anaconda3] >>> + read -r user_prefix

+ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
+ case "$PREFIX" in
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ '[' -e /Users/Nebula/anaconda3 ']'
+ '[' 0 = 1 ']'
+ mkdir -p /Users/Nebula/anaconda3
++ cd /Users/Nebula/anaconda3
++ pwd
+ PREFIX=/Users/Nebula/anaconda3
+ export PREFIX
+ printf 'PREFIX=%s\n' /Users/Nebula/anaconda3
PREFIX=/Users/Nebula/anaconda3
++ tail -n +588 /Users/Nebula/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
++ md5
+ MD5=ffe6c79627482cbbc073b4d7509bacb2
+ echo ffe6c79627482cbbc073b4d7509bacb2
+ grep ffe6c79627482cbbc073b4d7509bacb2
+ cd /Users/Nebula/anaconda3
+ unset PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME _CONDA_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME
+ CONDA_EXEC=/Users/Nebula/anaconda3/conda.exe
+ dd if=/Users/Nebula/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh bs=1 skip=27718 count=5050
+ dd if=/Users/Nebula/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh bs=16384 skip=2 count=903
+ dd if=/Users/Nebula/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh bs=1 skip=14827520 count=7405
+ chmod +x /Users/Nebula/anaconda3/conda.exe
+ export TMP_BACKUP=
+ TMP_BACKUP=
+ export TMP=/Users/Nebula/anaconda3/install_tmp
+ TMP=/Users/Nebula/anaconda3/install_tmp
+ printf 'Unpacking payload ...\n'
Unpacking payload ...
+ dd if=/Users/Nebula/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh bs=1 skip=14834925 count=8979
+ /Users/Nebula/anaconda3/conda.exe constructor --extract-tar --prefix /Users/Nebula/anaconda3
+ dd if=/Users/Nebula/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh bs=16384 skip=906 count=26470
+ dd if=/Users/Nebula/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh bs=1 skip=448528384 count=4122
+ /Users/Nebula/anaconda3/conda.exe constructor --prefix /Users/Nebula/anaconda3 --extract-conda-pkgs
+ PRECONDA=/Users/Nebula/anaconda3/preconda.tar.bz2
+ /Users/Nebula/anaconda3/conda.exe constructor --prefix /Users/Nebula/anaconda3 --extract-tarball
+ rm -f /Users/Nebula/anaconda3/preconda.tar.bz2
+ PYTHON=/Users/Nebula/anaconda3/bin/python
+ MSGS=/Users/Nebula/anaconda3/.messages.txt
+ touch /Users/Nebula/anaconda3/.messages.txt
+ export FORCE
+ mkdir -p /Users/Nebula/.conda
+ CONDA_SAFETY_CHECKS=disabled
+ CONDA_EXTRA_SAFETY_CHECKS=no
+ CONDA_ROLLBACK_ENABLED=no
+ CONDA_CHANNELS=https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main,https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main,https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r,https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro
+ CONDA_PKGS_DIRS=/Users/Nebula/anaconda3/pkgs
+ /Users/Nebula/anaconda3/conda.exe install --offline --file /Users/Nebula/anaconda3/pkgs/env.txt -yp /Users/Nebula/anaconda3
[y/N]: y
+ exit 1
Nebula@Infinitys-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED** I finally solved it. I erased the .condarc and .conda folder in my home directory. Then I ran the installer again and it worked.

It seems that the problem was that everytime I was trying to reinstall anaconda I was only erasing the anaconda3 folder and not the files/folders hidden in the home directory which were causing the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue with Miniconda (latest as of writing in July 2023) and there are no .condarc or .conda in my home directory. Anaconda should really make their installers more robust.